# Несколько параметров для mapAction/mapGetter vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

У меня есть определенная сущность PHONE, которая находится в store и oidcStore (тоже находится там). От  oidcStore мне нужно 'oidcIsAuthenticated', 'oidcIdToken', 'oidcAccessToken'. Чтобы достичь этого я пишу:
...mapGetters('oidcStore', ['oidcIsAuthenticated', 'oidcIdToken', 'oidcAccessToken']), как можно вписать в ..mapGetters PHONE,  чтобы все работало?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно расширить сразу два mapGetter`а

```
computed: {
   ...mapGetters('oidcStore', ['oidcIsAuthenticated', 'oidcIdToken', 'oidcAccessToken']),
   ...mapGetters('PHONE', ['getter1', 'getter2', 'getter3']),
},
```

Comment: спасибо большое, думал так нельзя делать